# How to fix cudaError 77 when copying back from device to host

Tags: cuda, runtime-error

I am writing  a simple example program to test memCpy and kernel run concurrency for a larger program. While writing this example, I stumbled upon error 77, aka cudaErrorIllegalAddress.

I read somewhere that that comes from the kernel accessing an invalid address, and not the memcpy itself. So I tried to index the lowest element of my input array (0). The error remained.

As it only is a small sample program, I will provide the whole code;

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BLOCKS 32
#define THREADS 16

__global__ void kernel(double *d_in, double *d_out) {
    int index = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    d_out[index] = d_in[index] + 5;
}

int main() {
    const int GPU_N = 2;
    const int data_size = 2048;
    const int cycles = 2;

    double *h_in, *h_out, *d_in, *d_out;

    h_in = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * data_size);
    h_out = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * data_size);

    for (int i = 0; i < data_size; i++) {
        h_in[i] = 21;
    }

    cudaError_t error;

    printf("1\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++) {
        //cuMalloc
        for (int j = 0; j < GPU_N; j++) {
            cudaSetDevice(j);
            cudaMalloc((void**)&d_in, sizeof(double) * data_size / 4);
            cudaMalloc((void**)&d_out, sizeof(double) * data_size / 4);

            printf("2\n");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < GPU_N; j++) {
            cudaSetDevice(j);
            cudaMemcpyAsync(d_in, h_in, sizeof(double) * data_size / 4, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            printf("3\n");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < GPU_N; j++) {
            cudaSetDevice(j);
            kernel<<< BLOCKS, THREADS, 0, 0 >>>(d_in, d_out);
            error = cudaGetLastError();
            printf("4\n");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < GPU_N; j++) {
            cudaSetDevice(j);
            error = cudaMemcpyAsync(h_out, d_out, sizeof(double) * data_size / 4, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
            printf("D2H %i\n", error);
            printf("5\n");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < GPU_N; j++) {
            cudaSetDevice(j);
            cudaFree(d_in);
            cudaFree(d_out);
            printf("6\n");
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < data_size; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", h_out[i]);
    }

    getchar();

}
```

So the output should be something like:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6
6
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6
6
26
26
26
26
26
.....
```

and then a spam of the result. It does so until the time it has to print `5`, then it outputs the `error 77`. Also, the output of the result is not `26` as expected, but `-842150451`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with this code.

1. As already pointed out in the comments, the `printf` format specifier here (`%i`) is wrong:

   ```
   printf("%i\n", h_out[i]);
   ```

   the quantity being printed is a `double` quantity, an appropriate format specifier would be `%f`.
2. This code will not work (for `GPU_N` greater than 1):

   ```
   for (int j = 0; j < GPU_N; j++) {
       cudaSetDevice(j);
       cudaMalloc((void**)&d_in, sizeof(double) * data_size / 4);
       cudaMalloc((void**)&d_out, sizeof(double) * data_size / 4);

       printf("2\n");
   }
   ```

   `d_in` and `d_out` are individual variables.  You don't get to somehow reuse them in this way.  When this loop goes through it's 2nd (or later) iteration, it will overwrite the pointer values that were previously assigned.  Later on this will result in code trouble, because for at least one of your kernel launches, you will be passing pointers to data that is not resident on that particular GPU (and this particular aspect of the problem is the proximal reason for the error 77 report.)

   One solution would be to provide arrays of pointers to make this work.
3. Some of the CUDA activity you are issuing in your loops may be asynchronous. Therefore, to be sure that your final printout of `h_out` shows expected results, you should wait for all work on the GPU to be finished.  One way to accomplish this is with another set of calls to `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`.  (I don't wish to argue about whether `cudaFree` is asynchronous or not.  I think this item is a sensible suggestion and noteworthy.  If you feel you can skip this item, do what you wish. For learning purposes, I think it is important to point this out.) For the reasons indicated in comments below, this item is not necessary/mandatory to get expected results for this particular code.  This answer isn't intended to be a complete treatise on asynchronous work issuance; for that I suggest further study of any of the relevant questions here on the `cuda` tag, and/or study of relevant CUDA sample codes.

Here's a modified code that has the above issues addressed  (I have shortened the final print-out loop):

```
$ cat t1477.cu
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BLOCKS 32
#define THREADS 16

__global__ void kernel(double *d_in, double *d_out) {
    int index = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    d_out[index] = d_in[index] + 5;
}

int main() {
    const int GPU_N = 2;
    const int data_size = 2048;
    const int cycles = 2;

    double *h_in, *h_out, *d_in[GPU_N], *d_out[GPU_N];

    h_in = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * data_size);
    h_out = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * data_size);

    for (int i = 0; i < data_size; i++) {
        h_in[i] = 21;
    }

    cudaError_t error;

    printf("1\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++) {
        //cuMalloc
        for (int j = 0; j < GPU_N; j++) {
            cudaSetDevice(j);
            cudaMalloc((void**)(&(d_in[j])), sizeof(double) * data_size / 4);
            cudaMalloc((void**)(&(d_out[j])), sizeof(double) * data_size / 4);

            printf("2\n");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < GPU_N; j++) {
            cudaSetDevice(j);
            cudaMemcpyAsync(d_in[j], h_in, sizeof(double) * data_size / 4, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            printf("3\n");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < GPU_N; j++) {
            cudaSetDevice(j);
            kernel<<< BLOCKS, THREADS, 0, 0 >>>(d_in[j], d_out[j]);
            error = cudaGetLastError();
            printf("4\n");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < GPU_N; j++) {
            cudaSetDevice(j);
            error = cudaMemcpyAsync(h_out, d_out[j], sizeof(double) * data_size / 4, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
            printf("D2H %i\n", error);
            printf("5\n");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < GPU_N; j++) {
            cudaSetDevice(j);
            cudaFree(d_in[j]);
            cudaFree(d_out[j]);
            printf("6\n");
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < GPU_N; i++){
        cudaSetDevice(i);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();}
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", h_out[i]);
    }


}
$ nvcc -o t1477 t1477.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1477
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
D2H 0
5
D2H 0
5
6
6
2
2
3
3
4
4
D2H 0
5
D2H 0
5
6
6
26.000000
26.000000
26.000000
26.000000
26.000000
26.000000
26.000000
26.000000
26.000000
26.000000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: So cudaFree is asynchronous or not?

Comment: The memory is not page locked doesn't that make the calls synchronized?

Comment: I don't wish to have a long discussion in the comments. @Oblivion you are evidently much farther along in the learning process than is OP. I think good programming practice suggests that you should allow for the possibility that `cudaFree` is asynchronous. If we're going to go into depth with critical instruction, a more productive line would be to suggest that you get `cudaMalloc` and `cudaFree` out of the processing loop. non-page-locked memory certainly suggests that the copy operation will not overlap with other activity, but it does not guarantee that the call is blocking or non-blocking.

Comment: Yes, specifically for the direction from device to host, the final `cudaMemcpyAsync` should be a blocking call, when the target is pageable memory.  When OP learns all this and modifies their code, then I think the suggestion in my point 3 will be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. I like your answers. I am learning a lot from them

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for answering. You mentioned in a comment that the ```cudaMemcpyAsync``` would be synchronized when using non-page-locked memory. Could you maybe explain this a bit further to me? Because that is a problem I am facing with the actual program I wrote this example for. The kernel launches are concurrent, but the ```cudaMemcpyAsync``` aren't. Additionally, NSight systems started to fail with tracing CUDA calls (posted about this on the CUDA forum, sadly the URL is to long to paste here)

Comment: Its documented [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/api-sync-behavior.html#api-sync-behavior).  The more general topic of writing code that orchestrates concurrency on GPUs is non-trivial, and I won't be able to give a tutorial in the space of the comments here.  As I mentioned in the answer, there are various resources to learn about CUDA concurrency, and how to write code to exploit it.